# Array and $_REQUEST

Tags: php, arrays, request

I need to use Ajax DataTable.
Order request is in array.
On inspect:
[image]
`Request parametersid: order[0][column]:"4" , order[0][dir]:"asc" and start:"0"` .

If i want to get value of "start" i use:

```
$str=$_REQUEST['start'];
```

Now i don't know how to get value "4" and "asc"?

I have tried with this `(current(current($_REQUEST['order'])))` and it returns "4", but for "asc", until now. no solution found.

Comment: What does `$_REQUEST['order'][0]['dir'];` return?

Comment: Thenk you! now it's works!

Answer (score 0):

Check values of

```
$_REQUEST['order'][0]["column"]
```

and

```
$_REQUEST['order'][0]["dir"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$str = $_REQUEST['order'][0]['column'];
```

and

```
$str2 = $_REQUEST['order'][0]['dir'];
```